# How to remove tweet images presenting on the Tweetview using iOS fabric.io SDK

Tags: ios, twitter, fabric.io

I am using **iOS** fabric.io SDK for Showing Twitter feed.
I don't want to show the tweet images presenting on the Tweetview, how to remove the tweet image ?

Answer (score 0):

You can loop all the subView of your TweetView and remove the imageView which you dont want to show,

```
for (UIView *subview in [Tweetview subviews]){
        NSLog(@"Class: %@", [subview class]);
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]){
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Retro. TweetView contains three images screen image, twitter image and posting image. Is there any direct fabric.io ios sdk api support ?

Comment: I havent used SDK so I am not sure about it, you can do some documentation reading for that.